# How to split a String sentence into words using split method in Java?

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split some sentences into words.

For example:

```
Upper sentence.
Lower sentence. And some text.
```

I do it by:

```
String[] words = text.split("(\\s+|[^.]+$)");
```

But the output I get is:

```
Upper, sentence.Lower, sentence., And, some, text.
```

And it should be like:

```
Upper, sentence., Lower, sentence., And, some, text.
```

Notice that I need to preserve all the characters (.,-?! etc.)

Comment: What is the purpose of this relatively complex regex, simply splitting on `\\.` should work.

Comment: Maybe the usual `.split("\\W+")` will do. Unless you need to handle hyphens and apostrophes, and suchlike.

Comment: Maybe I didnt specified that clearly in my question but I need to preserve all characters, that is: commas, periods etc. Using \\W+ deletes them all, and I need output like Upper, sentence., Lower, sentence., And, some, text.

Comment: so you want to split by spaces??

Comment: Yes, and by newlines. I edited my main post.

Comment: You could save your (and our) time by simply searching for "java split with whitespaces" in Google.

Comment: Sorry to take your precious time Wiktor. All the answers in Google states that I should use .split("\\s+"); that doesnt help in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace dots, commas, etc... for a white space and split that for whitespace

```
String text = "hello.world this   is.a sentence.";
String[] list = text.replaceAll("\\.", " " ).split("\\s+");
System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(list)));
```

Result: `[hello, world, this, is, a, sentence]`

Edit:

If is only for dots this trick should work...

```
String text = "hello.world this   is.a sentence.";
String[] list = text.replaceAll("\\.", ". " ).split("\\s+");
System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(list)));
```

> [hello., world, this, is., a, sentence.]

Comment: I also need to preserve any characters, so my output should be like: Upper, sentence., Lower, sentence., And, some, text.

Comment: I update the answer

Comment: It does work now. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

in regular expressions `\W+` match one or more non word characters.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

So if you want to get the words in the sentences you can use `\W+` as the splitter.

```
String[] words = text.split("\\W+");
```

this will give you following output.

```
Upper
sentence
Lower
sentence
And
some
text
```

**UPDATE :**
Since you have updated your question, if you want to preserve all characters and split by spaces, use `\s+` as the splitter.

```
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
```

I have checked following code block and confirmed that it is working with new lines too.

```
String text = "Upper sentence.\n" +
            "Lower sentence. And some text.";
    String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
    for (String word : words){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

Comment: I also need to preserve any characters, so my output should be like: Upper, sentence., Lower, sentence., And, some, text.

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The expression `\\s+` means "1 or more whitespace characters". I think what you need to do is replace this by `\\s*`, which means "zero or more whitespace characters".

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into sub strings using the following line of code:

```
String[] result = speech.split("\\s");
```

For reference: https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010006

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer for updated question

```
    String text = "Upper sentence.\n"+
            "Lower sentence. And some text.";
```

[just space] one or more OR  new lines one or more

```
    String[] arr1 = text.split("[ ]+|\n+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
```

result:

```
 [Upper, sentence., Lower, sentence., And, some, text.]
```

Comment: I also need to preserve all characters, so the output must be like Upper1, sentence2., Lower3, sentence4., And5, some6, text7, 10.

Comment: I updated answer